# A-Frame: I am trying to add a click function that will change the color of a box. Why isn't it working?

Tags: aframe

I am trying to start by adding a simple click function to a box that will change its color to red. Can you please have a look at my script and html and please tell me what I am doing wrong?

HTML(only the element meant to change color):

```
<a-box id='soundbox' position='0 2 -5' color="#6173F4" rotation="0 45 45 opacity=" 0.8" depth="1" alongpath="path:2,2,-5 -2,1,-2.5 0,1,-1; closed:false; dur:5000; delay:4000; inspect:false;" change-colors></a-box>
```

Script:

```
var soundbox = document.querySelector('#soundbox');

AFRAME.registerComponent('change-color', {
  init: function(){
    this.soundbox = soundbox;
    this.el.addEventListener('click', this.onClick.bind(this));
  },
  onClick: function(){
    soundbox.setAttribute('color', 'red');
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

There is a very good description of how to create a component in A-Frame in the [Building a Basic Scene Tutorial](https://aframe.io/docs/0.5.0/guides/#event-listener-component-intermediate) on the A-Frame website.

Your component would look like this:

```
AFRAME.registerComponent('change-color', {
  schema: {
    color: {default: '#666'}
  },
  init: function(){
    var data = this.data;
    this.el.addEventListener('click', function(){
      this.setAttribute('color', data.color);
    })
  }                
});
```

And your `a-box`:

```
<a-box
   position="0 2 -5"
   color="#6173F4"
   rotation="0 45 45"
   opacity=" 0.8"
   depth="1"
   change-color="color: #f00"
   >
</a-box>
```

You also need to add a cursor to the scene in order to click on entities. You do this by attaching it to the camera entity:

```
<a-camera position="0 -0.5 0">
  <a-cursor scale="0.5 0.5" color="#fff"></a-cursor>
</a-camera>
```

The whole code is here: https://glitch.com/edit/#!/enshrined-energy

And the working example: https://enshrined-energy.glitch.me/